# changeDate event in jQuery UI datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In this datepicker is event `changeDate` -> http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/

What is the equivalent in jQuery UI datepicker?

Answer (score 1):

```
onSelect: function( String dateText, Object obj )
```

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect

> Called when the datepicker is selected. The function receives the
>   selected date as text and the datepicker instance as parameters. this
>   refers to the associated input field.

Comment: `$('#field').datepicker().on('changeDate', my_function);`  - how to replace this using onSelect?

Comment: `$('#field').datepicker({ onSelect: my_function });`

Answer (score 0):

```
  $(".date").datepicker({
    onSelect: function() {
       .............
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be the equivalent of the [onSelect](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect) method in Jquery UI.